Counting number of days from event, till another event in R
data.frame(
  scrape_date = as.Date(c("2023-01-01", "2023-01-02", "2023-01-03", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-05", "2023-01-06", "2023-01-07", "2023-01-08")),
  own_product_id = c("00617","00617","00617","00617","00617","00617","00617","00617"),
  own_price = c(70, 70, 70, 70, 70,70,70,71),
  comp_price = c(70, 71, 71, 71, 71,71,71,71)
)

#   scrape_date own_product_id own_price comp_price
# 1  2023-01-01          00617        70         70
# 2  2023-01-02          00617        70         71
# 3  2023-01-03          00617        70         71
# 4  2023-01-04          00617        70         71
# 5  2023-01-05          00617        70         71
# 6  2023-01-06          00617        70         71
# 7  2023-01-07          00617        70         71
# 8  2023-01-08          00617        71         71

if I wanted to count the number of days it takes from when comp_price changes, till own_price is the same? how would I do it? its been doing my head in sorry
expecting an output like
product_id   time_taken_to_match
00617                     6 days 


You can use cumsum() to determine when own_price catches up comp_price.
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(own_product_id, grp = cumsum(own_price == comp_price)) %>% 
  summarise(time_taken_to_match = diff(range(scrape_date)), .groups = "drop") %>%
  filter(time_taken_to_match > 0)

# # A tibble: 1 × 3
#   own_product_id   grp time_taken_to_match
#   <chr>          <int> <drtn>             
# 1 00617              1 6 days


Thanks for think,. does it work if i want to check if its a permanent change? for example, if own_price goes  70, 70, 71, 70, 71 , 71,71,71
would you do a lead x3 to confirm the next three prices (71 match price) are the same or how would you approach this bit

@JamesMadds it sounds like a new issue. I think you can open a new issue with more detailed description, and provide example data and expected output.

Base R using a wrapper f() inside tapply() + array2DF(), and doing the (re)-naming manually:
f = \(x) { with(x, { idx = which(own_price == comp_price)
    difftime(scrape_date[idx[2L]], scrape_date[idx[1L]]) - 1L }) }
tapply(X, list(product_id = X$own_product_id), f) |> 
  array2DF(responseName = "time_taken_to_match")

# returns
  product_id time_taken_to_match
1      00617                   6


Thanks for think,. does it work if i want to check if its a permanent change? for example, if own_price goes  70, 70, 71, 70, 71 , 71,71,71
would you do a lead x3 to confirm the next three prices (71 the match price) are the same or how would you approach this bit

What @DarrenTsai says. Also, please define "permanent change" then. Three times or permanent?

Bit late, but here's another take with a column who checks if a price stays the same (or higher) for n days ahead:
library(tidyverse)

# Bigger toy data
toy_data <- tibble(
  scrape_date = today() - days(23:1),
  own_product_id = "00617",
  own_price =  c(70, 70, 70, 70, 70,70,70,71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 74),
  comp_price = c(70, 71, 71, 71, 71,71,71,71, 70, 71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 73, 73, 74, 74, 73, 74, 73, 73, 74))

# Number of days `comp_price` must be equal or greater than
hold_days <- 3

# ´comparison_id`: groups price with an unique id every time prices are same/not
# `comparison`: same/not price
# `comp_price_hold`: if `comp_price` stays the same or higher for the next `hold_days`
new_data <- toy_data %>%
  mutate(
    comparison_id   = consecutive_id(own_price, comp_price),
    comparison      = if_else(own_price == comp_price, "same", "not"),
    
    comp_price_hold = map_chr(
      seq_along(comp_price),
      \(x) if_else(
        any(comp_price[intersect((x + 1:hold_days), 1:nrow(toy_data))] < comp_price[x]), 
        "not", "hold"))) %>% 
  
  mutate(.by = comparison_id, n_days = row_number())

The output:
# A tibble: 23 × 8
   scrape_date own_product_id own_price comp_price comparison_id comparison comp_price_hold n_days
   <date>      <chr>              <dbl>      <dbl>         <int> <chr>      <chr>            <int>
 1 2024-04-14  00617                 70         70             1 same       hold                 1
 2 2024-04-15  00617                 70         71             2 not        hold                 1
 3 2024-04-16  00617                 70         71             2 not        hold                 2
 4 2024-04-17  00617                 70         71             2 not        hold                 3
 5 2024-04-18  00617                 70         71             2 not        hold                 4
 6 2024-04-19  00617                 70         71             2 not        not                  5
 7 2024-04-20  00617                 70         71             2 not        not                  6
 8 2024-04-21  00617                 71         71             3 same       not                  1
 9 2024-04-22  00617                 71         70             4 not        hold                 1
10 2024-04-23  00617                 71         71             5 same       hold                 1
11 2024-04-24  00617                 72         71             6 not        hold                 1
12 2024-04-25  00617                 72         71             6 not        hold                 2
13 2024-04-26  00617                 73         72             7 not        hold                 1
14 2024-04-27  00617                 73         72             7 not        hold                 2
15 2024-04-28  00617                 73         73             8 same       hold                 1
16 2024-04-29  00617                 73         73             8 same       hold                 2
17 2024-04-30  00617                 73         74             9 not        not                  1
18 2024-05-01  00617                 73         74             9 not        not                  2
19 2024-05-02  00617                 73         73            10 same       hold                 1
20 2024-05-03  00617                 74         74            11 same       not                  1
21 2024-05-04  00617                 74         73            12 not        hold                 1
22 2024-05-05  00617                 74         73            12 not        hold                 2
23 2024-05-06  00617                 74         74            13 same       hold                 1

And for the number of days where prices stays the same or differs, just slice_max by comparison_id ordering by `n_days:
# `slice_max` gives the number of days with same/not prices for each period `comparison_id`
> slice_max(new_data, by = comparison_id, order_by = n_days)
> slice_max(new_data, by = comparison_id, order_by = n_days)
# A tibble: 13 × 8
   scrape_date own_product_id own_price comp_price comparison_id comparison comp_price_hold n_days
   <date>      <chr>              <dbl>      <dbl>         <int> <chr>      <chr>            <int>
 1 2024-04-14  00617                 70         70             1 same       hold                 1
 2 2024-04-20  00617                 70         71             2 not        not                  6
 3 2024-04-21  00617                 71         71             3 same       not                  1
 4 2024-04-22  00617                 71         70             4 not        hold                 1
 5 2024-04-23  00617                 71         71             5 same       hold                 1
 6 2024-04-25  00617                 72         71             6 not        hold                 2
 7 2024-04-27  00617                 73         72             7 not        hold                 2
 8 2024-04-29  00617                 73         73             8 same       hold                 2
 9 2024-05-01  00617                 73         74             9 not        not                  2
10 2024-05-02  00617                 73         73            10 same       hold                 1
11 2024-05-03  00617                 74         74            11 same       not                  1
12 2024-05-05  00617                 74         73            12 not        hold                 2
13 2024-05-06  00617                 74         74            13 same       hold                 1

Created on 2024-05-07 with reprex v2.1.0
